# In nginx in which variable do I get the main domain

Tags: nginx

I want to forward all these subdomains in any scheme to the respective main domain in https. I don't want to have several server directives.

```
server {
    server_name *.autocosts.info
                *.autocouts.info
                *.autocostos.info
                *.autocosti.info
                *.autocustos.info
                *.autocosturi.info
                *.autokoszty.info;

    listen 80;
    listen 404;
    listen 443 ssl;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This does not seem to work. Does `$host` include subdomain? How can I get just the main domain (without subdomain)?

I know that I can get the [main domain](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) using `server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;` but that it is not restricted to the list of above domains.

Comment: What you want as result? Remove all subdomains and forward all requests to one host?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev I want to forward all these subdomains in any scheme to the **respective** main domain in https. Ex: `adsfasd.autocosts.info` -> `https://autocosts.info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to the rescue!

`^(\*\.)?([a-z\d][a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\.)(?<maindomain>auto[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\.info)+$`

`^(\*\.)?([a-z\d][a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\.)` matches subdomains.

`?<maindomain>` stores the naked domain in a variable called `$maindomain`

`auto` matches ‘auto’ which is present in all your domains.

`[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\` matches the rest of your domain

`\.info+` matches the .info part of your domains

(untested in nginx, but should work as regex).

Documentation used: [from the nginx.org website](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

[image: Regex tester]

So lets fix your server block:

```
server {
    server_name  ~^(\*\.)?([a-z\d][a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\.)(?<maindomain>auto[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\.info)+$;

    listen 80;
    listen 404;
    listen 443 ssl;

    return 301 https://$maindomain$request_uri;
}
```

This produces the following result when accessing the site:

`curl -I oi3j2.autocostos.info`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 15:48:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://autocostos.info
```

Comment: Thanks, but what `$host` stands for in this case on the last line, in case someone for example inserts `hello.autocosturi.info`?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to make it more clear. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll test it and I give you some feedback ASAP

Comment: I set as answer, but you solved my particular issue, you didn't answer the question :) In which variable is stored the main domain? Your solution is very case specific, my case.